# How to set underline using PdfContentByte

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I want to make the text underline and I can position it.
I tried 2 methods, pdfcontentbyte and chunk but it couldn't give me the result that I wanted.

By using pdfcontentbyte, I can't get the underline text but by using chunk I can't position it.

This is the code I tried by using pdfcontentbyte:

```
Title.BeginText();
Title.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(new Chunk("Electronic Generate Random Number Form", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, Font.UNDERLINE))), 80, 770, 0);
Title.EndText();
```

This is the code I tried by using chunk:

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\Calibri.ttf", "Identity-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
var font1 = new Font(baseFont, 16, Font.BOLD | Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK);
var font2 = new Font(baseFont, 14, Font.BOLD | Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK);

Chunk chunk1 = new Chunk(OrderInformation.Text, font1);
Chunk chunk2 = new Chunk(Label2.Text, font2);
document.Add(new Phrase(chunk1));
document.Add(new Phrase(chunk2));
```